# Ceiling fan has 2 Switches on the Wall

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

I have two switches on my wall by my bedroom door. Both of them control the fan they both turn on the light and fan. I know in houses black is hot, white is neutral or common and green is ground. I haven't looked inside the wall at the switches. It's been a good little while since I have done any electrical work, so I'm just confirming. Usually if there is a red wire and a blue wire red, is light, blue is fan. I'm thinking that they pig tailed the light and fan to the second plug so if I disconnect the blue or red wire from one switch if they are hooked up to both it should work properly with one switch for the fan and the other for the light. I'm a female, but I know about electricity - my dad taught me. I know I'm right, i just want it confirmed.

Comment: 1 - Female has nothing to do with anything here. 2 - Pictures of the ceiling wiring and the insides of both switch boxes would be helpful.

Comment: It just come to me i need to hook up a red wire a white wire and a black wire and a ground wire to one switch the black white and green coming from power source jump ( pigtail the black wire in to the second switch so the switch is hot hook up the blue wire to the second swirch for the fan and the green for ground right

Comment: Sounds plausible, but I'm not an expert (Harper or ThreePhaseEel can help more than I can) but most importantly, I can't guess the wiring - pictures are a key to figuring out other people's wiring problems.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Gender irrelevant.  Photos of inside of boxes not irrelevant.

Comment: White is *usually* neutral but if neutral is not needed in a cable, white can be re-tasked to be a hot.   A black/colored wire is always a hot.